# How to specify column types when importing in R

Tags: r, import

I am trying to import data from a csv file. All the columns except one should be imported as numeric. However, R is importing all as character variables. Now I know how to convert each column into numeric but I was wondering if this can be done during importing. Here is an example,

```
x <- c("argentina", "chile", "austria")
y <- c("-", "0.9", "7")
z <- c("19.7", "-", "7.3")

data <- data.frame(x, y, z)
str(data)
```

I have 8 columns so it is not efficient to convert them one by one. If there is a way to convert all to numeric except one during importing that will be great.

Comment: You can use fread() from data.table package which has option of specifying class with colClasses

Answer (score 0):

the `read.csv()` function has a flag colClasses which you can use to specify the type of each column.

Comment: That did not help. I am getting the following error,
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'a real', got '-'

I have missing values in the columns which are recorded as "-". Maybe that is what is causing the problem. But when you manually convert columns to numeric using as.numeric then it forces "-" to NA which is what I want.